# Check if cell array is a subset of a nother in Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, cell, subset

I have two cell arrays of strings as follows

```
 A={{a,b},{c},{d,e}}
 B={{a,b},{c,d},{e}}
```

I want to check if A is a subset of B, meaning that each cell in A has a super-cell in B.  In the given example it is not since A contains {d,e} while B does not have any cell that has those or more elements.
I think ismember should be useful in this case, but I just could not write down the logic.

Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

Given A and B

```
A={{'a','b'},{'c'},{'d','e'}}
B={{'a','b'},{'c','d'},{'e'}}
```

We can define a function `isSubset`, as follows:

```
isSubset = @(superSet,subSet)isempty(setdiff(subSet, superSet));
```

And test it:

```
isSubset(B{1}, A{1})  %true
isSubset(B{2}, A{2})  %true
isSubset(B{3}, A{3})  %false
```

---

Now we can use `isSubSet` and `cellfun` to define a function `isSubSetOfAny`, which checks to see if a particular subset is a subset of any of a set of sets, like this:

```
isSubSetOfAny = @(superSetSet, subSet) any(cellfun(@(x)isSubset(x, subSet), superSetSet));
```

And test it:

```
isSubSetOfAny(B, A{1})  %True
isSubSetOfAny(B, A{2})  %True
isSubSetOfAny(B, A{3})  %True
```

---

Now we can use `isSubSetOfAny` plus `cellfun` (again) to define `isEachMemberASubsetOfAny`, which performs the operation you describe:

```
    isEachMemberASubsetOfAny = @(superSetSet, subSetSet) all(cellfun(@(x)isSubSetOfAny(superSetSet, x), subSetSet));
```

And test it:

```
isEachMemberASubsetOfAny(B, A)    %Returns false

A_1 = {{'a','b'},{'c'},{'e'}};    %Define a variant of `A`
isEachMemberASubsetOfAny(B, A_1)  %Returns false
```

Answer (score 4):

How about something like:

```
function tf = is_subset(A,B)
    narginchk(2,2)
    assert(iscell(A) && all(cellfun(@iscellstr,A)));
    assert(iscell(B) && all(cellfun(@iscellstr,B)));

    for ia=1:numel(A)
        tf = false;
        for ib=1:numel(B)
            if all(ismember(A{ia},B{ib}));
                tf = true;
                break
            end
        end
        if ~tf
            break
        end
    end
end
```

With

```
[a,b,c,d,e] = deal('1','2','3','4','5');

A = {{a,b},{c},{d,e}};
B = {{a,b},{c,d},{e}};
is_subset(A,B)             %# false

B = {{a,b},{c,d,e},{e}};
is_subset(A,B)             %# true
```

Comment: Breaking the loops as soon as possible should lead to a pretty big performance improvement over the `cellfun` based approaches (including my own).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming a,b etc are strings you could do the following:

For each cell of A loop through B and see whether there is a cell in B for which all elements in the cell are member. Here is an example:

```
 A={{'abc','b'},{'c'},{'d','e'}};
 B={{'aabc','b'},{'c','d'},{'d','e'}}; %Remove the first a to return true


 subset = true;
 for i = 1:length(A)
     found = false; 
     for j = 1:length(B)
         found = found || all(ismember(A{i},B{j}));
     end
     subset = subset && found;
 end
 subset
```

Answer (score 2):

What are the types of a, b, etc.?  If they are strings, you can use `setdiff` to test whether one set is contained within another.  Suitable use of `cellfun` and `any` or `all` should do it.  Like so:

```
all(cellfun(@(a)any(cellfun(@(b)isempty(setdiff(a,b)),B)),A))
```

If they're some other type, you can make a simple m-file to check for a super-cell.  Replace `isempty(setdiff(a,b))` with a call to this function.  It will have to loop through the elements of `a` and check for each one whether it exists in `b`.

Comment: Thank you your code seems to be working but I could not understand it.. can you briefly unfold it?

Comment: `isempty(setdiff(a,b))` checks whether `b` is a superset of `a`.  The two cellfuns walk over the elements of `A` and `B`.  The end result is true iff all elements of `A` can find at least one element of `B` that is a superset.